# Storing/Retrieving array images with Pyautogui (AttributeError: 'Image' object has not attribute 'read')

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, docx, pyautogui

I'm trying to locate an image, then store another image relative to the first one within an array.  Afterwards, I want those images to drop into a word document using the docx library.  Currently, I'm getting the following error, despite a few different solutions I've tried below.  Here's the code:

```
import sys
import PIL
import pyautogui
import docx
import numpy

def grab_paperclip_images():
    '''
    This'll look at the documents that're on
    the current screen, and create images of
    each document with a paperclip.  I'll be
    testing on an unsorted screen first.
    '''
    image_array = []
    clip_array = find_all_objects("WHITE_PAPERCLIP.png")
    for item in clip_array:
        coordinates = item[0]+45, item[1], 222, item[3]
        image_array.append(pyautogui.screenshot(region=coordinates))
    return image_array

doc = docx.Document()
images = grab_paperclip_images()
for image in images:
     #print image
     #yields:  [<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=222x12 at 0x7CC7770>,etc]

     #Tried this - no dice
     #img = PIL.Image.open(image)
     #doc.add_picture(img)

     doc.add_picture(image)
doc.save("testDoc.docx")
```

Please let me know what I'm misunderstanding, and if you see any suggestions to make the code more pythonic, better scoped, etc.

As always, thanks for the help, sincerely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way around this.  I had to save the images to disk.  I could still reference the array, but I couldn't reference the image without saving it.  Here's my workaround:

```
def grab_paperclip_images():
    '''
    This'll look at the documents that're on
    the current screen, and create images of
    each document with a paperclip.  I'll be
    testing it on an unsorted screen first.
    INSPIRATION:
    bottom_record = pyautogui.screenshot(
        "LAST_RECORD.png",
        region=(
            last_clip[0],
            last_clip[1]+18,
            1100,
            14
            )
        )
    '''
    image_array = []
    clip_array = find_all_objects("WHITE_PAPERCLIP.png")
    count = 0
    for item in clip_array:
        coordinates = item[0]+45, item[1], 222, item[3]
        filename = "image"+str(count)+".png"
        image = pyautogui.screenshot(filename, region=coordinates)
        image_array.append(filename)
        count += 1
    return image_array


doc = docx.Document()
images = grab_paperclip_images()
for image in images:
    doc.add_picture(image)
doc.save("dingding2.docx")
delete_all(images)
```